# Achieving PHP-like workflow with Django dev server? (without reloading)

Tags: php, python, django, django-dev-server

The development of my django applications involves something very annoying: whenever I perform any change in my codebase, I need to restart the application. Django does it for me, cool, but it takes some time (even more for bigger apps) which I want to avoid.

I am a big fan of how it works in PHP: No restarts involved, I may test my changes as soon as I perform them.

My question is: is it possible to achieve the "change&run right away without waiting for dev server to reload" workflow with django project?

---

I know the title may sound confusing :) My question is about the final effect. I realize this is apples vs oranges and under the hood it works completely differently, I know that python dev servers are long running processes with global state and the code is loaded&compiled on startup, while PHP requests are completely separate from each other and in most dev setups the code is loaded&compiled on each request. I also realize that django dev server has a great automatic reload feature.

Comment: What? How are you running it now? `manage.py runserver` *does* reload changes automatically, unless they alter the models and migration is required, or you make a change that breaks syntax, etc.

Comment: as I wrote: I also realize that django dev server has a great automatic reload feature. It simply takes some time and I wonder if I can avoid it somehow

Comment: I updated the question, I hope it's less confusing now

Comment: Oh, I see; then: no, for the reasons you outline. You have to wait for the dev server to reload.